# NLog not creating files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logging, model-view-controller, nlog

I'm trying to use NLog to log activity from certain methods in my controller, but everytime I hit the method there is no log file created, here is my config:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<targets>
  <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
      layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}${exception:format=ToString}"
      fileName="${basedir}/test.txt"
      archiveFileName="${basedir}/{#}.txt"
      archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm_ss"
      archiveNumbering="Date"
      archiveEvery="Month"
      maxArchiveFiles="6" />
</targets>

<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" />
</rules>
</nlog>
```

Here is my logging code:

```
public static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

public static void DashboardLogging(string username, string changedField, string oldValue, string newValue, string taskName)
    {
        try
        {
            logger.Info(" User: " + username + " | Field Changed: " + changedField + " | Change: " + oldValue + " --> " + newValue + " | Affected Task: " + taskName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Fatal(ex + " - *ERROR*");
        }

    }
```

Looking inside of the logger I find that config is NULL:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to switch on [internal logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) to see what's happening?

Comment: BTW: [Tutorial](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial) See points 2 and 3 ... (4 could also shed some light)

Comment: I've tried internal logging and it yielded the same results, I will work through the tutorial linked and report back on my findings.

Comment: I tried following the tutorial and found that when I get the logger, the config appears to be null (see image in my question).

Comment: @Fildor thank you, your comment save my Day, precisely (4 could also shed some light)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by pulling out the config from my web.config file, putting that in a new Nlog.config file in a subfolder, then pointing to it just before I log.

Controller:

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
public static void DashboardLogging(string username, string changedField, string oldValue, string newValue, string taskName)
    {
        try
        {
            LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Views\\Dashboard\\Nlog.config");

            logger.Info(" User: " + username + " | Field Changed: " + changedField + " | Change: " + oldValue + " --> " + newValue + " | Affected Task: " + taskName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex, "*ERROR*");
        }

    }
```

Nlog.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
  </configSections>

  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwConfigExceptions="true">

    <targets>
      <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
          layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}${exception:format=ToString}"
          fileName="${basedir}/Log/test.txt"
          archiveFileName="${basedir}/Log/{#}.txt"
          archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm_ss"
          archiveNumbering="Date"
          archiveEvery="Month"
          maxArchiveFiles="6" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Now you are setting the configuration every time you log. That's super-fluent. You need to read the config once when your app starts.

Comment: But maybe your config was in the wrong place. I never had to do this. It just worked. See: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#configuration-file-locations

Comment: Mind that if you use it as standalone (outside of web.config) you need to have `<nlog>` as the root tag. If you post your (sanitized) web.config we maybe could see why nlog didn't pick up the config from web.config.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will proceed with your suggestions!